# How can I tell when a random a vector is isotropic?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-matrices

Isotropic random vectors crop up with some frequency when talking about random matrices. A random vector $X$ is defined to be *isotropic* if, in expectation, its outer product is the identity matrix: $\mathbb{E}[XX^T] = I$.

This is all well and good, and there appear to be many results reasoning about what you can say when working with isotropic random vectors (e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027.pdf)).

My problem is that I'm not sure when a random vector is isotropic. For example, if I draw a vector $X$ uniformly at random from the unit ball, is $X$ isotropic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your definition, an isotropic random vector is a vector such that, with $n$ the size of the vector space,
$$ 
\mathbb{E} [X_iX_j] = 0 \qquad \forall i,j \in \{1, \dots n \}, \;i\ne j \\
\mathbb{E} [X_iX_i] = 1 \qquad \forall i \in \{1, \dots n \}
$$
Thus if $X_i$ are i.i.d. centered gaussian variables of variance 1, the random vector is isotropic.

Considering a ball of radius $R$, for uniform vectors, in dimension 2, with $x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y = r cos (\theta)$:
$$
\mathbb{E} [X^2] = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}  
\iint_{r=0, \theta = 0}^{r=R, \theta = 2\pi} (r\cos(\theta))^2 r dr d\theta = \frac{R}{3}
$$
So for $R=1$ the vectors can certainly not be isotropic.

You can show for centered vectors that if they belong to a sphere they can not be isotropic.